# jquery equivalent for getcomputedstyle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I found this getComputedStyle polyfill in a [JavaScript plugin](https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js)

```
if (!computed) {
  window.getComputedStyle = function(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
      var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
      if (prop === "float") {
        prop = "styleFloat";
      }
      if (re.test(prop)) {
        prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
          return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
        });
      }
      return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
    };
    return this;
  };
}
```

Is there any jQuery equivalent for getcomputedstyle();

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the getter version of [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

From doc

> The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the
>   first matched element, especially in light of the different ways
>   browsers access most of those properties (the getComputedStyle()
>   method in standards-based browsers versus the currentStyle and
>   runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms
>   browsers use for certain properties.

like

```
$(el).css('color')
```

Comment: but does this take into account browser defaults and/or user CSS? i suspect that's what @Arya is looking for with 'computed style'

Comment: @Plato: From the docs: "*The .css() method is a convenient way to get a style property from the first matched element, especially in light of the different ways browsers access most of those properties (the getComputedStyle() method in standards-based browsers versus the currentStyle and runtimeStyle properties in Internet Explorer) and the different terms browsers use for certain properties*"

Comment: @Arya note that your polyfill may do more harm than good - just let jQuery do its thing.

Comment: Looks like it does get properties from user agent stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/c8RDW/

Comment: jQuery x getComputedStyle are different... not same. Example a try `$('p:before').css('color','red')` is not work... only javascript is work a real. jQuery just plugin.

Comment: CSS is not solution at all. For example how can you get RGB color data of semitransparent element? I suppose we still need to use native JS here.