# getComputedStyle like javascript function for IE8

Tags: javascript, gwt, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to write a Javascript function inside a Java GWT code that gets the value of the following styles

```
"direction", "fontFamily", "fontSize", "fontSizeAdjust", "fontStyle", "fontWeight", "letterSpacing", "lineHeight", "padding", "textAlign", "textDecoration", "textTransform", "wordSpacing"
```

The `getComputedStyle` was useful in all browsers except IE8 which doesn't support such function as I understand

I looked at the posts about smiler subject here but all of them failed to get one of the above styles

smiler subject posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733365/cross-browser-ie8-getcomputedstyle-with-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137507/jquery-equivalent-for-getcomputedstyle).

Here is my initial solution without the IE8 special case

```
public static native String getStyleProperty(Element element, String style) /*-{
        if (element.currentStyle) {
            return element.currentStyle[style];
        } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
            return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(
                    style);
        }
    }-*/;
```

Any suggestions for a good `getComputedStyle` replacement function for IE8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a similar method to my original solution with an additional case to handle inline styles, also the way to check if the current document support the `getComputedStyle` is a bit different it checks in the `document.defaultView` instead of the window itself, here is the full function

```
public static native String getStyleProperty(Element el, String prop) /*-{
        var computedStyle;
        if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) { // standard (includes ie9)
            computedStyle = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[prop];

        } else if (el.currentStyle) { // IE older
            computedStyle = el.currentStyle[prop];

        } else { // inline style
            computedStyle = el.style[prop];
        }
        return computedStyle;

    }-*/;
```

[source](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/GoneVertical-Core/src/org/gonevertical/core/client/style/ComputedStyle.java?r=3084)

Answer (score 8):

Look over here: http://snipplr.com/view/13523/

The code:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
    window.getComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
        this.el = el;
        this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
            var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
            if (prop == 'float') prop = 'styleFloat';
            if (re.test(prop)) {
                prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
                    return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
                });
            }
            return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('test'), "");

    alert(compStyle.getPropertyValue("color"));
    alert(compStyle.getPropertyValue("float"));
    alert(compStyle.getPropertyValue("background-color"));
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `this` the return value should be a newly created object. Now it assigns the `el` and `getPropertyValue` properties to the window object and subsequent calls to `window.getComputedStyle` will override them. (Also a minor nitpick: both the `{1}` in the regular expression and the if statement testing if the regular expression matches are unnecessary)

Comment: You declared the second argument, `pseudo`, but don’t do anything with it. How do I get the computed style of pseudo elements?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution. It is based on [this Trick](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102291), but then I've expanded it in case to resolve two problems.

First problem is that `borderTopWidth` (`left`,`bottom`,`right`) in `el.currentStyle` returns as adjective - `'thin'`, `'medium'`, `'thick'` - or `'none'`. The Trick will return exception.

And second problem - some values will not be calculated correctly. Such as `opacity` and some else. You can check it by yourself by applying this Trick-method to all the properties:

```
var _style = el.currentStyle;
for (var key in _style) {
      /// here is the Trick.....
}
```

At last, here is my solution, based on assumption, that I know all the properties I want to get by this function:

```
if (!window.getComputedStyle) window.getComputedStyle = function(el){
    var __style = el.currentStyle,
        _style = {};
    for (var i in __style) {
        _style[i] = __style[i]; 
    }

    // IE8 returns border widths as adjectives
    if (style.indexOf("border") === 0)
        switch (_style[style]) {
            case "thin":
                _style[style] = 2;
                break;
            case "medium":
                _style[style] = 4;
                break;
            case "thick":
                _style[style] = 6;
                break;
            default:
                _style[style] = 0;
        }

    // based on http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102291        
    var leftCopy = el.style.left;
    var runtimeLeftCopy = el.runtimeStyle.left;
    // some properties, that I want to use
    _styleParams = {
        left : 1,
        right : 1,
        top : 1,
        bottom : 1,
        width : 1,
        height : 1,
        borderLeftWidth : 1,
        borderRightWidth : 1,
        borderTopWidth : 1,
        borderBottomWidth : 1,
        paddingLeft : 1,
        paddingRight : 1,
        paddingTop : 1,
        paddingBottom : 1,
        marginLeft : 1,
        marginRight : 1,
        marginTop : 1,
        marginBottom : 1
    }
    for (var key in _styleParams) {             
        el.runtimeStyle.left = el.currentStyle.left;            
        el.style.left = _style[key];                        
        _style[key] = el.style.pixelLeft;
        el.style.left = leftCopy;
        el.runtimeStyle.left = runtimeLeftCopy;             
    }


    // opacity for IE8
    if (_style.filter.match('alpha')) {
        _style.opacity = _style.filter.substr(14);
        _style.opacity = parseInt(_style.opacity.substring(0, _style.opacity.length-1)) / 100;
    } else {
        _style.opacity = 1;
    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is more complete polyfill for IE8/getComputedStyle which should handle all cases:

https://github.com/jonathantneal/Polyfills-for-IE8/blob/master/getComputedStyle.js

Comment: Any Idea how I can put this code inside a Java GWT code like my code in the question above?

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with Java/GWT but you should be able to include that file in the < head > section of the page ( jsp if you use that )

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far was from another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890142/3672465. It's a standalone version of the jQuery curCSS() code; you may need to adjust it to suit your needs (as Maksim notes in his answer). Here's a compact version of the IE 8 portion, if you just want something to drop in.

```
if( !window.getComputedStyle && document.documentElement.currentStyle ){
    function getStyles( elem ){ return elem.currentStyle; };
    function curCSS( elem, name, computed ){
        var rnum = /^([+-]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|))(?!px)[a-z%]+$/i;
        var t = 'left', l, rs, rsL, c = computed || getStyles( elem ), 
            r = c ? c[ name ] : undefined, s = elem.style;
        if( r == null && s && s[ name ] ){ r = s[ name ]; }
        if( rnum.test( r ) && !/^(top|right|bottom|left)$/.test( name ) ){
            l = s[t]; rs = elem.runtimeStyle; rsL = rs && rs[t]; 
            if( rsL ){ rs[t] = elem.currentStyle[t]; } 
            s[t] = name === 'fontSize' ? '1em' : r; r = s.pixelLeft + 'px'; 
            s[t] = l; if( rsL ){ rs[t] = rsL; }
        }
        return r === '' ? 'auto' : r;
    };
}
```